# Filtering the result of the find command, so that it returns only directories

Tags: bash, shell, find, grep

Is it possible to get only the results from find that are directory paths? Using find with some option, or using grep or some other utility the results are piped into as a filter?

I thought something like `find | grep */$` might work, but it doesn't. From some other testing where I "grepped for" a folder with a specific name it seems like I get a hit for `folder_name$` but not for `folder_name/$`. This seems conterintuitive. How can I grep for lines that end with `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `-type d` option is used for this.

For example:

```
$ find /boot -type d
/boot
/boot/grub
/boot/grub/locale
/boot/grub/fonts
/boot/grub/i386-pc
```

Here's the relevant section of the man page:

```
   -type c
          File is of type c:

          b      block (buffered) special

          c      character (unbuffered) special

          d      directory

          p      named pipe (FIFO)

          f      regular file

          l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the
                 -follow option is in effect, unless the symbolic link  is
                 broken.  If you want to search for symbolic links when -L
                 is in effect, use -xtype.

          s      socket

          D      door (Solaris)
```

Comment: thanks! I looked at the manpage, but I still find them a bit bewildering, must have missed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to [Zero Piraeus' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88061/22565), if you want to include symlinks that resolve to directories:

- with GNU find:

  ```
   find . -xtype d
  ```
- POSIXly:

  ```
   find . -exec test -d {} \; -print
  ```

  which you can optimise to

  ```
   find . \( -type d -o -type l -exec test -d {} \; \) -print
  ```

If you want to follow symlinks when descending the directory tree, you'd do:

```
find -L . -type d
```

which would report directories and symlinks to directories. If you don't want the symlinks:

- with GNU find:

  ```
   find -L . -xtype d
  ```
- POSIXly:

  ```
   find -L . -type d ! -exec test -L {} \; -print
  ```

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND/)   # directories
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND-/)  # directories, or symlinks to directories
print -rC1 -- ***/*(ND/)  # directories, traversing symlinks
print -rC1 -- ***/*(ND-/) # directories or symlinks to directories,
                          # traversing symlinks
```