# Grep only in files that are in certain folders

Tags: bash, shell, grep, directory, directory-structure

I want to grep for `interesting string`, but only in specific folder/file combinations, such as `myfolder/myfile.out`.

The directory I'm grepping from may have these combinations in subdirectories of varying depths (otherwise I could just `grep 'interesting string' myfolder/myfile.out`) and I also do not want to get results from any `myfile.out` that is located in a directory with a different name, for example `/deeply/nested/directory/structure/myfolder/myfile.out` shall be grepped, but not `/deeply/nested/directory/structure/notmyfolder/myfile.out`.

Comment: Maybe helpful towards an acceptable answer: [Filtering the result of the find command, so that it returns only directories](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88060/13260)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly you are looking for something like:

```
find . -path "*/myfolder/myfile.out" -exec grep <string> /dev/null {} +
```

Comment: This works, but I get an xargs warning `a NUL character occured in the input. It cannot be passed through in the argument list. Did you mean to use the --null option?`

Comment: just edit the answer to a more suitable answer. the previous one had an error that would take into account myfile.xyz files as well.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, the `**/` [glob](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) means “under any level of directory nesting”:

```
grep 'interesting string' **/myfolder/myfile.out
```

In bash: `shopt -s globstar` then as above. Beware that in bash ≤4.2 this traverses symbolic links to directories. This feature doesn't exist yet in the ancient version of bash on OSX.

In ksh93: `set -G` then as above.

This may fail if the total length of the file names is too long. In this case, you can fall back to calling `find` which will run `grep` in batches:

```
find -path '*/myfolder/myfile.out' -exec grep -H 'interesting string' {} +
```

or if you can't rely on GNU tools:

```
find -name myfolder -exec sh -c 'grep "$0" /dev/null "$1/myfile.out"' 'interesting string' {} \;
```

though if you have zsh then it once again comes to the rescue with [`zargs`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs):

```
zargs -- **/myfolder/myfile.out -- grep 'interesting string' /dev/null
```

A different approach is to use a different tool that combines grep and directory traversal in fancier ways than GNU grep. For example you can use the [silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher):

```
ag -G '/myfolder/myfile\.out$' 'interesting string'
```